# googleanalytics-api-V4 get maximun results to save the results in to dataframe

Tags: google-analytics-firebase

This is my first query expecting some answers. I'm using the below report request and I'm getting error for pageToken .

```
enter code here
return analytics.reports().batchGet(
  body={
    'reportRequests': [
     {
      'viewId': VIEW_ID,
       'pageToken': '100001',
       'pageSize': 100000,
       'dateRanges': [{'startDate': 'yesterday', 'endDate': 'yesterday'}],
       'metrics': [{'expression': 'ga:sessions'},{'expression':'ga:users'}, 
       {'expression': 'ga:bounces'},{'expression':'ga:pageviews'}],
       'dimensions': [{'name': 'ga:dimension1'},{'name': 'ga:date'}, 
       {'name':'ga:pageTitle'}]
       }] 
      }).execute()
```

My query is for my particular query I have data more than 100000 rows and I want to load all the rows into particular table. Please can someone help me how to get all the data from the request.